# How to use combinations

Tags: python

I have 6 lists, say,

```
a=[1,1,0,0]
b=[0,1,1,0]
c=[0,0,1,1]
d .... until f.
```

I want to generate the results of the sum for all possible combination of the lists starting from 2 lists till 6 lists. For example, I want to calculate the result of a+b, a+c, .. a+f. Then, a+b+c, a+b+d, ...etc. I know hoe to compute the result of two or three lists but I am stuck in how to generate the combinations for lists. I tried to define list of lists and use combinations with argument 2 to generate all possible 2 combinations for 3 lists (as example) as follows:

```
import itertools

alphabet = [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]]

combos = itertools.combinations(alphabet, 2)

usable_combos = []
for e in combos:
    usable_combos.append(e)
```

But this simply does not produce anything. When I print `usable_combos`, I get:

```
[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]]
```

My question is: using combinations, how can I produce all possible combinations (from 2 to 6 combinations) for the 6 different sets I have?

Comment: A copy-paste of your source code produces a set of 3 combinations. Are you sure you're printing the right variable?

Comment: As a side note: That loop you have at the end is exactly equivalent to `usable_combos = list(combos)`, except slower and harder to read.

Comment: The output is not `[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]]`, it's `[([0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]), ([0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]), ([0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0])]`. Which is exactly what I'd expect. If you expect something different, please show us _what_ you expect, and we can tell you how to get it.

Comment: Also: what "6 different sets" do you have? You have 3 lists of 3 numbers each. I can't think of any way to get 6 out of that.

Comment: The 3 I posted are just an example but I actually have 6 sets (a-f) as started in the beginning.

Comment: @user2192774 see my updated answer, is that what you wanted? Otherwise add the expected output in the question body.

Comment: Why the `d .... until f` bit? It's not clear how to continue the pattern, and you've saved yourself three lines of copy-and-paste for one line that you had to write? Unless you're on a 300 baud modem and can't stand waiting 30 seconds for that paste, why not just give us the actual data? And a snippet of the actual expected output, instead of a description of that output? You're making things harder for yourself and for everyone trying to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `range(1, len(lis)+1)` to get the value for the second parameter(`r`) that is passed to `combinations`. or `range(2, len(lis)+1)` if you want to start from 2.

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> lis = [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]]
>>> for i in range(1, len(lis)+1):
...     for c in combinations(lis,i):
...         print c
...         
([0, 0, 0],)
([0, 0, 1],)
([0, 1, 0],)
([0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1])
([0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0])
([0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0])
([0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0])
```

As pointed out may @abarnert in the comment, may be you want this:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> flatten = chain.from_iterable
>>> ans = [list(flatten(c)) for i in range(2, len(lis)+1) for c in permutations(lis,i)]
>>> pprint(ans)
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: From what I can tell from the first paragraph, he doesn't want this, he wants `[0,0,0] + [0,0,1]`, then `[0,0,0] + [0,1,0]`, then `[0,0,0] + [0,0,1] + [0,1,0]`, then `[0,0,1] + [0,1,0]`, but not the original individual lists. Which is… not combinations, and I'm not sure what it is. So I don't think this answers his question, but I don't know if his question is answerable without clarification…

Comment: Maybe he wants `[flatten(c) for i in range(2, len(lis)+1) for c in combinations(lis, 1)]` (where `flatten = itertools.chain.from_iterable`)?

Comment: @abarnert May be he wants this, I've updated my answer to add the `flatten` version.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary: I actually want the sum of each combination starting from 2 combination to 6 combinations. But, the first part of your answer does the purpose if creating the combinations (which was not working with me as the code in my post shows). Then, I will add some code to sum every combination and append the sum to a final list.